# How can I connect rSyslog to an SQL database?

Tags: mysql, rsyslog

I'm trying to connect rsyslog to a remote SQL database. Here's (part of) my /etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
$ModLoad ommysql
*.* action(type="ommysql" server="logs.example.com" serverport="3306" db="logs" uid="..." pwd="...")
```

I can send logging messages to the terminal and /var/log/messages by doing `logger -s "test message"`, but they don't appear in the database. I have installed rsyslog-mysql and mysql is installed on the machine as well. Here's what I've tried so far:

- I looked in /var/log/messages after restarting rsyslog to see if it was failing to start or to parse the config file (it's doing fine).
- I connected to the database using the `mysql` command - the user exists and can connect to the server, and it has the right permissions.
- I used `tcpdump` to listen to traffic going to port 3306. There is none when I use `logging`, but I can see traffic when I connect with `mysql`, whether I get the password right or not.

This is on CentOS 6.5 with rsyslog 5.8.10.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using the "new style" configuration (used on rsyslog v6+), but the version of rsyslog I had installed was 5.8.10. I changed the `*.*` line to the following (the old style):

```
*.* :ommysql:logs.example.com,logs,rsyslogger,password
```

and it worked.